# Saving values from User Control

Tags: c#, aspx-user-control

I have an aspx page. On `pageLoad` a call a method that loads a user control

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadUC();
}
```

This loads the user control onto the page (into a placeholder) passing a few generic values.

```
private void LoadUC()
{
    ucTS ctrl = (ucTS)Page.LoadControl(_ucTSPath);
    ctrl.ParentId = 0;
    ctrl.addNew = false;
    phFG.Controls.Add(ctrl);
}
```

The user control (which contains a repeater) loads the initial placeholder as well as another placeholder on the initial page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadItems();
}

private void LoadBOMItems()
{
    List<Item> dtItem;

    if (ParentId == 0)
    {
        if (ViewState["ItemFG"] == null)
        {
            dtItem = //Gets list of items
        }
        else
        {
            dtItem = (List<Item>)ViewState["ItemFG"];
        }
        ViewState["ItemFG"] = dtItem;
    }
    else
    {
        if (ViewState["Items" + ParentId] == null)
        {
            dtItem = //get list of items
        }
        else
        {
            dtItem = (List<Item>)ViewState["Items" + ParentId];
        }
        ViewState["Items" + ParentId] = dtItem;
    }

    if (dtItem.Count > 0)

        rptTSItem.DataSource = dtItem;
        rptTSItem.DataBind();              
    }
}
```

in the binding, I bind the repeater, but I am also adding more of the same user control.

The problem comes when I click add a new item to the repeater.  The initial click, everything saves fine and a new row is added.  The second click the user control is not found on the initial page and so the save method is not fires.  The 3rd click, everything is fine, the 4th, the user control is not found.  This keeps happening. Why is my usercontrol not always found?  I have tried doing a postback check in multiple places, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: have you set breakpoints, and stepped thru the code..? sounds like you should do that first

Comment: I have.  The first time, every breakpoint gets hit as it should (Page Load, then onclick, then save).  The second time, the user control page load gets hit, but it never reaches the onclick method.  This is where the save function is called.

Comment: I am currently looking at the possibility that my onclick button is getting cleared (I clear the controls of the placeholder so I can repopulate the update panel with the new information).  I am trying to dynamically add the button but so far no such luck.

Answer (score 0):

I am still not 100% sure why the event would fire properly every OTHER time as opposed to just the first time, but the solution was simply adding an ID to the user control.

```
private void LoadUC()
{
ucTS ctrl = (ucTS)Page.LoadControl(_ucTSPath);
ctrl.ParentId = 0;
ctrl.addNew = false;
ctrl.ID = "someID"
phFG.Controls.Add(ctrl);
}
```

and whenever I re-added the user control from within the user control, I pass the same ID.